# Android: VolleyRequestQueue stops sending when app exits?

Tags: android

If the app queues a request into `VollyeRequestQueue` and exits right away (like below), will the queue stop and not send the request?

```
VolleyRequestQueue.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(lastRequest)
finish();
```

In my test, the app seems to abort the queue. How do I avoid that behavior? or what is a recommended way of making sure the network request gets sent when the app exits?